# Angular / Material / Datepicker - No provider found for DateAdapter

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, material-design, angular6

I have a question about: `angular / material / datepicker`.

I have a dummy project that works properly with the following files:

**/src/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatStepperModule, MatInputModule, MatButtonModule, MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StepperComponent } from './components/stepper/stepper.component';
import { DatepickerComponent } from './components/datepicker/datepicker.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        StepperComponent,
        DatepickerComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**/src/app/components/datepicker/datepicker.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is the API I'm inspecting:

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

I would like to know, why if I comment the import of: `MatNativeDateModule` on the file: `app.module.ts` I get on the browser, the error:

```
ERROR Error: "MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation."
```

On the `API` section they don't mention that module.

They mention that module on the `Overview` section but don't provide too much details.

Could you clear this for me? This looks sometimes very obscure.

Thanks!

Comment: swap the order of `MatNativeDateModule` and `MatDatepickerModule` in your imports

Comment: what?, why?, could you explain more what you mean?

Comment: I'm guessing that the MatNativeDateModule needs to be built after the MatDatepickerModule, and this may be cause the problem. Core routing modules and animation modules have similar effects. The order of your imports matters and the example has them in that order!

Comment: but my question is not about the order, but why if I remove that import, I get that error?, thanks!

Comment: Apologies, I misread. The module `MatNativeDateModule` has a service named `DateAdapter` that needs to be *provided* by a parent module in order to be **injected**. This is where the provider/@Injector tags come in. Because you don't import `MatNativeDateModule`, there is no module to provide the Injectable `DateAdapter` and thus the error is thrown.

Comment: and where in my code do I use the DateAdapter?

Comment: You are using it in the `MatDatepickerModule` (which is where the request originates).

Answer (score 0):

the idea is to keep it optional for developers to choosing the date provider they want without any restriction for so they didn't mention it under **overview** not under **API** since API is just for core API of angular material design that gives you control and accessibility for specific material component.

`matNativeDateModule` is not module developed as whole by give parse to the time is just module to tell `matDatePicker` hey when you use date object please use the native javascript date object. which maybe you don't wanna to use it and use your own date object or javascript date library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com).